# Angularjs - Getting the $index from the first ng-repeat and use it to the second ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a nested ng-repeat. I want to use the $index of the first ng-repeat to the second ng-repeat. Here is my sample illustration of the problem:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in obj">
<div ng-repeat="row in anotherObj[$index].name">{{row.firstName}}</div></div>
```

Where $index refers to the 'item' in the first ng-repeat which is the index position (int) of the object and 'name' is an object inside the 'anotherObj'.

Does the value of $index will be taken from 'item' from the first ng-repeat or from 'row' in the second ng-repeat?

Comment: Please edit your post and share your obj and anotherObj data.

Comment: @Antikhippe I think there's no need to post the data inside the objects because my issue here is about the $index if it's value will be taken from the first ng-repeat or the second ng-repeat. You can assume that here is data inside the objects. Thank you!

Comment: Try to use $parent.$index instead of $index

Comment: @Antikhippe just the answer I've been looking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$parent.$index`, Like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in obj">
  <div ng-repeat="row in anotherObj[$parent.$index].name">
    {{row.firstName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

`$index` will give you index for `row` only

Comment: Accepted this answer since you are the first to answer. Thanks for the answer. Plus one :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try `$parent.$index`. `ng-Repeat` creates a new scope so your first `ng-repeat` should be the parent of the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`$parent.$index`**

```
  <div ng-repeat="row in anotherObj[$parent.$index].name">
    {{row.firstName}}
  </div>
```